VMs in nat network not reachable by the host. Guest Virtual interfaces not showing. (QEMU / KVM - VirtManager)
First of all, sorry for the lack of technical details. Virtualization is not my area of expertise.

I use QEMU / KVM with Virt manager to manage some VMs I use for personal labs and testing on my computer. I noticed today that my ansible scripts stopped working when attempting to run them.
After some (Very) superficial troubleshooting, I noticed that the virtual interfaces of the VMs were not showing on the host, only the gateway of the NAT network (192.168.100.1/24):
$ ip -br a
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
enx68da73a9fe50  DOWN
virbr0           DOWN           192.168.122.1/24
wlp1s0           UP             192.168.1.39/24 fe80::3a12:abf3:475a:eab2/64
virbr1           UP             192.168.100.1/24 #This is the gateway of the network
vnet2            UNKNOWN        fe80::fc54:ff:fe7a:3845/64

Usually, the virtual interfaces of the VMs will also show here.
In virt manager, the network XML is as follows:
<network connections="1">
  <name>kubernetes</name>
  <uuid>2cd1e633-432c-4de5-9590-955905b111ab</uuid>
  <forward mode="nat">
    <nat>
      <port start="1024" end="65535"/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name="virbr1" stp="on" delay="0"/>
  <mac address="52:54:00:2f:61:73"/>
  <domain name="kubernetes"/>
  <ip address="192.168.100.1" netmask="255.255.255.0">
  </ip>
</network>

The VMs under the network are not only active, but are verified to be working as intended (E.g. They can ping other VMs in the network, reach the public internet, etc). No network configuration changes have been made to any of the VMs. The Network uses static IPs.
Any ideas what could be going on?
